# Parsing TCP payloads using a custom spec

Tags: node.js, networking, udp, multicast, algorithmic-trading

My goal is to create a parser for TCP packets that are using a custom spec from the [Options Price Reporting Authority](https://www.opraplan.com/) found [here](https://assets.website-files.com/5ba40927ac854d8c97bc92d7/5ffe181b7f69028301e3ec36_OPRA%20Pillar%20Output%20Specification%20v2.pdf) but I have no idea where to start. I've never worked with low-level stuff and I'd appreciate if I got some guidance.

The huge problem is I don't have access to the actual network because it costs a huge sum per month and all I can work off is the specification. I don't even if it's possible. Do you step by step parse each byte and hope for the best? Do you first re-create some example data using the bytes in the spec and then parse it? Isn't that also difficult since (I think) that TCP spread the data to multiple blocks?

Comment: You don't have to worry about how tcp actually sends the data (and resends if packages get lost). All you need to do is open a tcp connection (e.g. `net.Dial("tcp", addr)`) and write/read to/from it.

Comment: The tricky part is of course understanding the spec correctly. I'd say creating some sample data from the spec is a good first step. Maybe you can also find someone to look over your sample data before you implement it... someone who knows the expensive network or possibly get your hands on other code that works with the data (e.g. the other side you will talk to.) If that is not an option, maybe you can create a mock app that sends your sample data and records what is received and run it against the real network (paying for a few minutes for it), to get some verification.

Comment: @TehSphinX It costs $2000/month. I have contacted them and see if I can get something for a lower price. So first step is to get some sample data either using the spec or get it another way. Then use that data and parse it with the help of the spec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's quite an elaborate data feed. A quick review of the spec shows that it contains enough information to write a program in either nodejs or golang to ingest it.

Getting it to work will be a big job. Your question didn't mention your level of programming skill, or of your network engineering skill. So it's hard to guess how much learning lies ahead of you to get this done.

A few things.

1. It's a complex enough protocol that you will need to test it with correctly formatted sample data. You need a fairly large collection of sample packets in order to mock your data feed (that is, build a fake data feed for testing purposes). While nothing is impossible, it will be very difficult to build a bug-free program to handle this data without extensive tests.

   If you have a developer relationship to the publisher of the data feed, you should ask if they offer sample data for testing.
2. It is *not* a TCP / IP data feed. It is an [IP multicast datagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_multicast) feed. In IP multicast feeds you set up a server to listen for the incoming data packets. They  use multicast to achieve the [very low latencies necessary for predatory algorithmic trading](https://www.worldcat.org/title/flash-boys-a-wall-street-revolt/oclc/1166766836).

   - You won't use TCP sockets to receive it, you'll use a different programming interface called [UDP datagrams](https://nodejs.org/api/dgram.html#dgram_udp_datagram_sockets)
   - If you're used to TCP's automatic recovery from errors, datagrams will be a challenge. With datagrams you cannot tell if you failed to receive data except by looking at sequence numbers. Most data feeds using IP and multicast have some provision for retransmitting data. Your spec is no exception. You must handle retransmitted data correctly or it will look like you have lots of duplicate data.
   - Multicast data doesn't move over the public network. You'll need a virtual private network connection to the publisher, or to co-locate your servers in a data center where the feed is available on an internal network.
   - There's another, operational, spec you'll need to cope with to get this data. It's called the [Common IP Multicast Distribution Network Recipient Interface Specification](https://assets.website-files.com/5ba40927ac854d8c97bc92d7/5fda7a9f67d49209823c9ae5_Common_IP_Multicast_Distribution_Network_Specification_121620v1_48.pdf). This spec has a primer on the multicast dealio.

You can do this. When you have made it work, you will have gained some serious skills in network programming and network engineering.

But if you just want this data, you might try to find a reseller of the data that repackages it in an easier-to-consume format. That reseller probably also imposes a delay on the data feed.

Comment: Thank you so much Jones! My primary goal is to learn so that's why I decided not to use any of their vendors (re-sellers).

Comment: If you're learning so you can have a demo project that will get you hired by a firm in the commodities trading business, the US$2K ./ month cost of the data feed is a worthwhile investment. Those guys pay big bucks. If you're learning for the general purpose of learning to handle network packets, there are plenty more accessible network data feeds you can work with.  Network Time Protocol comes to mind. So do RTP and RTSP.

Comment: I am a student (full stack development) so it's still a hefty amount but I completely get your point. I am very much interested in the stock market and my future plans is to create a product on top this service. But I also want to learn networking so this was an attractive option. Thanks once again Jones!

Comment: If you haven't already done so, study the details of networking.  TCP, IP, DNS, IPv4 addressing, IPv6 addressing, routing, TLS, etc. To get this Options Price Reporting Authority demo working, you will need to know that stuff.  The typical "full-stack" curriculum teaches you that the network comes down from heaven like rain. It's not so.  And, be sure to read [Michael Lewis's book about the automated trading business](https://www.worldcat.org/title/flash-boys-a-wall-street-revolt/oclc/1166766836): you'll learn the *why* of a lot of this.

Comment: Absolutely. I know this is an opinionated question but is there any books or video courses you recommend? Preferably videos because I have ADHD and can't sit still.

Comment: I don't know much about video courses, I lack the patience to sit through them. Pluralsight and O'Reilly Media have good reputations. I have subscribed to the latter for many years. They have the books and the video training. Doubly useful if you live someplace without a decent tech library.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227443/discussion-between-o-jones-and-nima).